# export to excel datagrid adobe flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I found the following code here only I kept the same in my Adobe Flex project but after clicking on the export to Excel button I can't see any Excel opening in addition to that my datagrid is filling with the column names which I intended to give to my Excel.

```
    public function roExport_export_Result(e:ResultEvent):void
    {
        if(e.result.length != 0)
        {
            btnExportToExcel.enabled = true;

            var arrExportResult:Array = e.result as Array;

            xlsFile = new ExcelFile();
            var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();

            sheet.resize(arrExportResult.length+1,14);

            sheet.setCell(0,0,'Id');
            sheet.setCell(0,1,'Full Name');
            sheet.setCell(0,2,'Gender');
            sheet.setCell(0,3,'Birth Date');
            sheet.setCell(0,4,'College Name');
            sheet.setCell(0,5,'Qualification');
            sheet.setCell(0,6,'Email Id');
            sheet.setCell(0,7,'Mobile');
            sheet.setCell(0,8,'Position Applied For');
            sheet.setCell(0,9,'Technology Interested');
            sheet.setCell(0,10,'User Name');
            sheet.setCell(0,11,'Password');
            sheet.setCell(0,12,'Exam Date');
            sheet.setCell(0,13,'Percentage');
            sheet.setCell(0,14,'IsActive');

            for(var i:int=0;i<arrExportResult.length;i++)
            {
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 0, arrExportResult[i].Id);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 1, arrExportResult[i].FullName);
                if(arrExportResult[i].Gender == 1)
                {
                    arrExportResult[i].Gender = "Male"
                }
                else
                {
                    arrExportResult[i].Gender = "Female";
                }
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 2, arrExportResult[i].Gender);
                var date:String = arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.date.toString();
                var month:String = (arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.month + 1).toString();
                var year:String = arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.fullYear.toString();
                var bDate:String = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                arrExportResult[i].BirthDate = bDate;
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 3, arrExportResult[i].BirthDate);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 4, arrExportResult[i].CollegeId);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 5, arrExportResult[i].QualificationId);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 6, arrExportResult[i].EmailId);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 7, arrExportResult[i].Mobile);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 8, arrExportResult[i].PositionName);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 9, arrExportResult[i].TechForTraining);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 10, arrExportResult[i].UserName);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 11, arrExportResult[i].Password);
                var date:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.date.toString();
                var month:String = (arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.month + 1).toString();
                var year:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.fullYear.toString();
                var hour:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.hours.toString();
                var min:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.minutes.toString();
                var sec:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.seconds.toString();
                var cDate:String = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate = cDate;
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 12, arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 13, arrExportResult[i].Percentage);
                sheet.setCell(i+1, 14, arrExportResult[i].IsActive);
            }

            dataGridResult.dataProvider = arrExportResult;

            xlsFile.sheets.addItem(sheet);      
            bytes = xlsFile.saveToByteArray();                  
        }
        else
        {
            arrExportResult = new Array();
            dataGridResult.dataProvider = arrExportResult;
            btnExportToExcel.enabled = false;
            xlsFile = new ExcelFile();
            var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();
            Alert.show("No Records Found",parentApplication.alertTitle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is confusing. Where did you find this code? Did you write it? Is it in a project you're maintaining? Did you find it on the web? Where is your Export Button? Have you stepped through code? Are you receiving an error? What libraries are used to make this work?  What are the ExcelFile and Sheet classes?  Where is your DataGrid code? Since this method looks like a result handler, what is it a result of?  I suspect your dataGrid changes is because of this line: dataGridResult.dataProvider = arrExportResult; which modifies a dataProvider on a list based class.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the byte Array you have to use a FileReference.save(bytes); call to pop up the window that prompts the user for where to save the data... as Flextras/Jeffry says the data grid is probably changing due to the dataGridResult.dataProvider line.  If you're doing this as an AIR based desktop app you can use the File and FileStream class to write out the bytes directly without prompting the user.

So long as you have FP 10+ targetted

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

For AIR:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/com/adobe/livecycle/content/File.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeBytes()

Comment: In a browser... I thought you couldn't save things unless the user requested it (such as a button click).  There would be no way to trigger that in a result handler.

Comment: ahh you are correct this does need to be invoked from a click or keyboard press